# Is there any way to terminate all EC2 instances by tags with Ansible?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, yaml, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

So I have a very simple ansible script to terminate EC2 instances that I filtered using tags.

```
- name: Destroy Web Instance.
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  
  vars_files:
  - group_vars/all

  tasks:
  - name: Gather Web Instance EC2 Facts.
    ec2_instance_info:
      region: "{{ region }}"
      filters:
        "tag:Type": "web"
      aws_access_key: "{{ec2_access_key}}"
      aws_secret_key: "{{ec2_secret_key}}"
    register: ec2_web

  - name: Kill EC2 Instance
    ec2:
      instance_ids: "{{ ec2_web.instances[0].instance_id }}"
      state: absent
      region: "{{ region }}"
      aws_access_key: "{{ec2_access_key}}"
      aws_secret_key: "{{ec2_secret_key}}"
```

The script worked fine, but when there is multiple instances within the same tags, it only terminates the first one. Is there any way to terminate every instances within those tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
instance_ids: "{{ ec2_web.instances[0].instance_id }}"
```

This is just one instance and hence terminating only one. you can use `count_tag` to count the instances with a specific tag and terminate the exact number of instances using `exact_count`

example at the end of this documentation

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/ec2_module.html

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm embarrased that it turned out to be such a simple fix.

Answer (score 0):

The "issue" with your code was that you were getting the `instance_id` only the first instance (`instances[0]`).
One solution would be to extract all the `instance_id` with something like:

```
ec2_web.instances | map(attribute='instance_id') | list
```

another would be to loop the task for each element in `ec2_web.instances`.